# Output table from 2 different inputs in Shiny App (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I currently output a table using the following code in my server.R

```
values <- reactiveValues(textInput = NA)

observe({

    if(input$button1 > 0) {
        values$textInput <- isolate(input$textInput)
  } 
})


output$table <- renderTable({
    load("recsForVisual.Rda", envir = .GlobalEnv)
    addRec(recsForVisual, values$textInput)    
 })
```

The "addRec" is simply a function that returns the data frame for the table. What I need to do is make a change from another action button in my ui.R (button2) but have that change reflected in the same table.  I have tried creating another output$table that takes in a new reactive value (from the button2) and also putting both reactive values in the same output$table.  This isn't working.  How can I have the same table output input from 2 different isolated action buttons?

Comment: What does button 2 do? Do you want to trigger `addRec` again or some different function?

Comment: Button 1 adds text while button 2 removes text.  So button 2 is an action button tied to a selectInput dropdown.  When you select the text from the options that you want to remove it removes the text. But this isn't captured in the output.  I need to reload the entire page to the change.

Comment: Would be clearer if you show your attempt.